# How to create an interface containing an array of objects defined by another interface?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In a class component, I'm trying to correctly type the state object by defining an interface which contains an array of objects defined by another interface.

When I access the state property, it is typed as `never[]` ?

```
interface OrdersProps extends RouteComponentProps<any>, React.Props<any> { }

interface OrderType {
  ingredients: { [index: string]: number },
  totalPrice : number
}

type OrdersType = OrderType[]

interface OrdersState {
  // orders: { ingredients: {[index: string]: number}, totalPrice: number}[] <- not working
  // orders: Array<OrderType> // <- not working 
  orders: OrdersType // <- not working
}

class Orders extends React.Component<OrdersProps, OrdersState> {
  state = {
    orders: []
  }
  render() {
    const orders = this.state.orders // <- orders of type `never[]` ??

    return (
      <div>
        ...
      </div>
    )
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    // fetch data and set state
  }
}
export default Orders
```

Comment: It seems to me that it's likely set as `never[]` simply as an optimization. i.e. you've intentionally set the value to `[]`, so it always contains zero elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a result of TypeScript seeing that the `state` is initialised with an object that contains an empty orders array, which is `never` populated. (In non-strict mode I believe it would result in `any[]` rather than `never[]`.

If you tell TypeScript that you know better with a type assertion, you'll find that the `never[]` issue goes away... so as long as something, somewhere, populates that array you'll be correct to tell it so.

```
state = {
    orders: []
} as OrdersState;
```